# How do I select a column using variables?

Tags: vba, excel, variables

I have a value in a cell which I need to use for selecting a column. For eg I've inserted "AB" in cell 'A4' and "AF" in cell 'A5'. I have to select the columns from 'AB' to 'AF'. How do I pass the values from cells? I need to select columns depending on the values entered in cells 'A4' and 'A5'

Comment: check my updated answer... you just need to put EntireColumn

Answer (score 0):

```
Columns(Range("A4").Value & ":" & Range("A5").Value).Select
```

Alternatively, using the Range and Cells properties:

```
Range(Cells(1, Range("A1").Value), Cells(1, Range("B1").Value)).EntireColumn.Select
```

Comment: First one having some issues, anyway second one is helpful.. thank u

Answer (score -1):

**try this:**

```
Range(Range("A4").Value, Range("A5").Value).EntireColumn.Select
```

Comment: It is helpful when selecting a range of cells. I have to select the entire column.

For eg: Column("A":"F").Select

Comment: @Sunny This doesn't work if cells contain only column names. They have to include any row number, e.g. `AB1` and `AF1`.

Comment: @Kapol care about reading what OP wants carefully and then consider down voting. excerpt from the question-**"For eg I've inserted "AB" in cell 'A4' and "AF" in cell 'A5'. I have to select the columns from 'AB' to 'AF'."** It doesn't deserve a down vote.

Any answer can not cover all the scenarios... all our answers pertains to a specific use case... I'm forced to think you're a noob.

Comment: @Kapol did you try running the codes or you just want to prove you're a genius, Sir?

Comment: @AjMatthew okay, I'm glad it helped. Now can you please upvote and marked it as answer if it solved your purpose, thanks.